# Model a chemical phenomenom

Tags: mathematical-modeling, chemistry

I have a chemical phenomenon to model for my research. I'll try to be clear while explaining my problem.

I created little molecules (let's call them "emitters"), which emit a signal. When the emitters are not too close from each other (i.e, when the concentration is low), the signal is proportional to the concentration. However, when they are close, the signal is weakened.

Then, I created a receptor. It's basically a big molecule which can host plenty of emitters. When the emitters are stuck on the receptor, they are close, the "local concentration" is high, so the signal is weakened.

[image: the phenomenom]

On the picture, the emitters are the blue spheres. And here is a curve of the signal. In x, you have the concentration of the emitters, and in y, you have the intensity of the signal.

[image]

During phase A, the signal increases because the local concentration of the emitters is not high enough.
Then, it reaches phase B, where adding more emitters on the receptor weakens the signal. As you can see, there is a plateau where adding more emitters change nothing.
And then you have phase C, where the emitters are not on the receptor, because the receptor is full. Then the signal is linear.

My goal:
Model (which means get a function y=f(x)) the phenomenon. I would need a function describing the process. I'll then fit my experimental points to this function, and hopefully get back some informations:

- the concentration where f(x) is max, before entering phase B
- the concentration where f(x) starts to be linear (indicating the saturation of the receptor)

I know I could get these infos by reading the graph, but it's not really accurate. Plus, if possible, I'll extend this function to include some parameters like the charge of the molecules, or their size.

So, is it possible to do something ? I'm not very good in maths.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE! You are more likely to get a good answer to your question if you follow a few guidelines.  In particular, make your question clear. Are you asking us to find a function $y=f(x)$ that models your graph? What do you mean by $f(x)=x$?

Comment: Thank you ! Yes sorry, I wrote too fast. It's y=f(x).

Answer (score 1):

Let $X$: the number of emitter molecules bound to a single receptor and $Y$: the strength of the signal from that single receptor.

One way to summarize your experimental result is to see how $Y$ depends on $X$.  (Can you count $X$ precisely or approximately?)

Then it is possible to model the receptor as a square lattice, for example, where each small square can be occupied by an emitter molecule. When two emitter molecules are positioned in neighboring squares (or within the distance of three squares etc.), their signal becomes weakened. You can simulate the model numerically and compare it to your above result to fit the parameters. Different experimental conditions can be incorporated into the model by changing the size of a small square or other parameters.

Comment: That's actually a very good idea. I like the concept.
To answer your question, I can count X more or less precisely. If you look at the graph in my question, you have the concentration of the emitters in abscissa. And I know the concentration of the receptor (it's 55. It's set for an experiment). So if the concentration of my emitters is 5000, I have 5000/55=90.9 -> 91 emitters per receptor. But how would be your lattice ? If the max number of emitters per receptor is 50, would it be a square or a rectangle ?

Comment: I think the lattice should reflect the actual shape of the receptor, but you could start with a rectangle (if it's 2D) or a cuboid (if it's 3D).

Comment: I have no idea about the structure of my receptor, but it's probably not 2D. But modeling a cube (and possibly representing/drawing it) is hard business. Do you think a 2D lattice, where the borders are not the limits (I mean the first square of the first line is considered to be just next to the last square of the first line) could do it ? Something like a planisphere, to model the distance between my emitters.

Comment: Yes, periodic boundary conditions are often used in mathematical / physical modeling and are a good starting point.